# Sequence of Form_Activate() and Form_Load() in VB6

Tags: vb6

In what sequence are the Form_Load() and the Form_Activate() functions called in VB6? What does "Activate" mean in the context of forms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [KB138819](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138819):

> The `Form_Load` event fires when a form is first loaded into memory.

and

> [...] the `Activate` event is called every time a form becomes the active window, as long as the focus has moved between forms in the application.

Comment: +1 See also [life cycle of visual basic forms]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242139(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can try it yourself!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    MsgBox "Form_Activate"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "Fom_Load"
End Sub
```

Form_Load msgbox always come out first!

Comment: It's always better to check the documentation for stuff like this. You really can't exhaustively test for all possible conditions, and just making assumptions is very likely to lead to hard-to-detect bugs, those that can only be reproduced under "field" conditions where you can't easily attach a debugger.